# Why is WordPress showing local host ip address instead of domain name in url?

Tags: localhost

I am very new to Wordpress and I recently migrated my site after buying the domain name. While, I can look up my website with the url and it works fine, when I go into the wordpress back end, it the url shows https://127.0.0.1/wordpress/. I have been stuck on this problem a long time and I would really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your website url in your wordpress config file ( in my case `/etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php` )

```php
define('WP_SITEURL','http://....');
```